# How can I override a method of an anonymous generic class?

Tags: java, generics, design-patterns, gwt, anonymous-types

I am working on GWT project with JDK7. It has two entryPoints (two clients) that are located in separate packages of the project. Clients share some code that is located in `/common` package, which is universal and accessible to both by having the following line in their respective xml-build files:

```
    <source path='ui/common' />
```

Both clients have their own specific implementations of the Callback class which serves their running environments and performs various actions in case of failure or success. I have the following abstract class that implements `AsyncCallback` interface and then gets extended by its respective client.

```
public abstract class AbstractCallback<T> implements AsyncCallback<T> {
    public void handleSuccess( T result ) {}
    ...
}
```

Here are the client's classes:

```
public class Client1Callback<T> extends AbstractCallback<T> {...}
```

and

```
public class Client2Callback<T> extends AbstractCallback<T> {...}
```

In the `common` package, that also contains these callback classes, I am working on implementing the service layer that serves both clients. Clients use the same back-end services, just handle the results differently. Based on the type of the client I want to build a corresponding instance of `AbstractCallback` child without duplicating anonymous class creation for each call. I am going to have many declarations that will look like the following:

```
   AsyncCallback<MyVO> nextCallback = isClient1 ?
                    new Client1Callback<MyVO>("ABC") {
                        public void handleSuccess(MyVO result) {
                            doThatSameAction(result);
                        }
                    }
                    :
                    new Client2Callback<MyVO>("DEF") {
                        public void handleSuccess(MyVO result) {
                            doThatSameAction(result);
                        }
                    };
```

That will result in a very verbose code.

The intent (in pseudo-code) is to have the below  instead:

```
AsyncCallback<MyVO> nextCallback = new CallbackTypeResolver.ACallback<MyVO>(clientType, "ABC"){
            public void handleSuccess(MyVO result) {
                doThatSameAction(result);
            }
        };
```

I was playing with the factory pattern to get the right child instance, but quickly realized that I am not able to override `handleSuccess()` method after the instance is created.

I think the solution may come from one of the two sources:

1. Different GWT way of dealing with custom Callback implementations, lets call it alternative existent solution.
2. Java generics/types juggling magic

I can miss something obvious, and would appreciate any advice.
I've read some articles here and on Oracle about types erasure for generics, so I understand that my question may have no direct answer.

Comment: In which class is `doThatSameAction`?

Comment: Also, are you using [Gin](https://code.google.com/p/google-gin/)?

Comment: Looks to me like you should define your own properties in `.gwt.xml` and use deferred binding to do the heavy lifting. This looks an awful lot like a square wheel...

Comment: @durron597 that same class. Not using Gin, can it help?

Answer (score 1):

### Refactor out the `handleSuccess` behavior into its own class.

The `handleSuccess` behavior is a separate concern from what else is going on in the `AsyncCallback` classes; therefore, separate it out into a more useful form. See [Why should I prefer composition over inheritance?](https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/q/134097/88986)

Essentially, by doing this refactoring, you are transforming an overridden method into [injected behavior](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dependency_injection) that you have more control over. Specifically, you would have instead:

```
public interface SuccessHandler<T> {
    public void handleSuccess(T result);
}
```

Your callback would look something like this:

```
public abstract class AbstractCallback<T> implements AsyncCallback<T> {
    private final SuccessHandler<T> handler; // Inject this in the constructor

    // etc.

    // not abstract anymore
    public void handleSuccess( T result ) {
        handler.handleSuccess(result);
    }
}
```

Then your pseudocode callback creation statement would be something like:

```
AsyncCallback<MyVO> nextCallback = new CallbackTypeResolver.ACallback<MyVO>(
            clientType, 
            "ABC", 
            new SuccessHandler<MyVO>() {
                public void handleSuccess(MyVO result) {
                    doThatSameMethod(result);
                }
            });
```

The implementations of `SuccessHandler` don't have to be anonymous, they can be top level classes or even inner classes based on your needs. There's a lot more power you can do once you're using this injection based framework, including creating these handlers with automatically injected dependencies using [Gin](https://code.google.com/p/google-gin/) and [Guice `Provider`s](https://github.com/google/guice/wiki/InjectingProviders). (Gin is a project that integrates Guice, a dependency injection framework, with GWT).